# Is it possible to make something similar to Alcubierre's drive but in gas/liquid instead of spacetime?

Tags: simulations, warp-drives

Is it possible to use something similar to the Alcubierre's drive for traveling in the water or air? How could it be done?

Is it possible to make water flow around bubble keeping it non-disturbed inside the bubble?

---

Comment: how about a submarine

Comment: @AndrewSteane Submarine moves in water itself. It doesn't stay in moving bubble of water

Answer (score 2):

The most-advanced, ultrahigh-speed torpedoes work somewhat in this way. The torpedo blows a gas bubble around itself using rocket fuel and then uses a rocket motor to propel itself, continually rebuilding the bubble as it goes.

As you would expect, this is an incredibly noisy process which makes it easy to detect when one of these things has been launched at you from another sub. This in turn limits its utility in times of stealthy warfare in the deep.

Comment: Does this technique allow the torpedo to exceed the speed of sound in water? If so, it is only noisy after it has passed you.

Comment: @rob, excellent question- and then it would kill you before you could hear it- I do not know the answer though!